# Error while scaffolding Identity: Two Versions of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I'm attempting to add scaffolding for Identity in a blazor server app. When I do I get the error below (it's repeated about 25 times, I just capped the first two for brevity).

This is confusing me because it is stating there are two versions of AspNetCore.Identity, 6.0.0.0 and 2.2.0.0, both with the same PublicKeyToken.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems and i fixed them. Try to update all Nuged packages and delete identity pages and controllers then create again.